# Regex - find lines starting with 2 dashes containing single speech mark

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

Starting with this sample text:

```
-- Search for relevant Title, second half of the screen, under "Context Field Values" lists the main parts of the Flexfield
-- This lists the bits users see in Core Applications when they click into the DFF plus shows if there is a LOV linked to the field
-- It's a test
-- So is this

      SELECT fat.application_name
           , fdfv.title
           , fdfv.application_table_name
```

How can I use a RegEx in Notepad++ to find any lines starting with `--` and containing a single speech mark `'`?, so that only this line is returned:

```
-- It's a test
```

I tried a silly amount of things, such as:

- `[^--']`
- `[^--*']`
- `[*--*']`
- `--[']`
- `[--][']`
- `[']`
- `^--[']`
- `^--*\'*`
- `^--*'*`

But as you can see, I'm not too clever!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to match a line starting with `--` containing only a single `'`:

```bash
^\s*--[^'\r\n]*'[^'\r\n]*$
```

Make sure to keep MULTILINE mode on since we are using anchor `^`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Us2iTt/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `--`: Match `--`
- `[^'\r\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `'` and not a line break
- `'`: Match a `'`
- `[^'\r\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `'` and not a line break
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^--.*'.*$`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
    --      # 2 dashes
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    '       # a single quote
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
$       # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful reply. Is there a way the RegEx can be edited so that a line starting with `--` and where there is a character right after the `'` so that e.g. a line containing `it's` is returned but one containing `AND  user = 'SYSADMIN'` is not returned, and one containing e.g. `AND user = 'SYSADMIN' AND creation_date is not null'` is also not returned, because in both of the those cases, there is either an End of Line or a space after the `'`? i.e. I just need to flag lines starting with `--` and where there is a character immediately after the `'` e.g. as is case for `it's`'

Comment: @4532066: `^--.*'\S.*$` should do the job, `\S` stands for any character that is not a space. If this is valid for you, I'll modify my answer accordingly. If it doesn't, please edit your question and add more test cases and expected result.